# Can we just let "prepareFromRequest" to behave just like traditional non-Ajax page?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, let see how traditional non-Ajax page work. Suppose you have a page like the below link

```
abc.com#!search;item=car
```

In the traditional non-Ajax website, when first time you call "`abc.com#!search;item=car`", it will go to server and get data. After that you go to other page like "`abc.com#!customer;name=tom`" and then you hit back button it will go back to "`abc.com#!search;item=car`". However, this time it won't call to the server again cos it remembered it did before.

Now Here is the GWTP problem. Suppose the above `abc.com` was built in GWTP technology.

At the first time wen user enters the "`abc.com#!search;item=car`", the GWTP app will initialize the page "search" via `onBind`, then the `prepareFromRequest` will be called & it will go to server to get data.

That is Good, no problem. However, if we open a new page (like customer page) by using `revealPlace`, then we hit the back button it will go back to "search" page & it will call `prepareFromRequest` again. The `prepareFromRequest` will then make the exactly same call to server again. That is not good cos it wastes resource.

So I want the "prepareFromRequest" to be called ONLY at the time we initialise the page (run after onBind) & block the "prepareFromRequest" in all other page request (ex like user press the back button).

It mean "prepareFromRequest" should work just like traditional non-Ajax page mentioned above.

Can we do that? or

Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just check in your `prepareFromRequest` method if you have already a search result for that specific searchterm and only issue a call to the backend if it has changed?

Something like this:

```
public Presenter extends .... {

    String searchItem = null;
    List<DTO> searchResult = null;

    @Override
    public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest placeRequest) {
        super.prepareFromRequest(placeRequest);
        String item = placeRequest.getParameter("item",null));
        if (searchItem == null || !searchItem.equals(item)) {
            searchItem = item;
            // MAKE A CALL TO THE BACKEND AND STORE THE DATA IN A FIELD. 
            searchResult = GET_FROM_SERVER(searchItem);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: wait, suppose we searched searchItem="car", but what if user enter url "abc.com#search;searchTearm=bicycle", then we need a new search for this request. If i do like you then the system won't call "searchTerm=bicycle"

Comment: maybe i can check if 2 requests are exactly the same, but do you know the simplest way to check if 2 requests are exactly the same (the numbers of param are the same & the nametoken are the same.

Comment: Sure it will. The `if (seachItem == null || !searchitem.equals(item))` line will issue a new backend call when you haven't searched before or if the searchterm is different than the previous one